# Customise Spartacus Cart Path

Tags: checkout, spartacus-storefront

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, though a search didn't turn up any results.

Assuming I'm starting from a fresh Spartacus app, how can I customise the path of the cart page? By default it's /cart, but what if I want to change it to (for example) /checkout/cart?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `defaultStorefrontRoutesConfig` we have `cart: { paths: ['cart'] },`. You can replace it to anything.

You also need to replace the CMS cart page's label to `/checkout/cart`, so that the CMS cart page can be found and loaded.

Comment: Perfect, I followed both those steps and it worked. Many thanks!